# Iterating through specific elements of a vector using another vector

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, vector, iterator

Let's say I have a vector of strings as defined below.

```
std::vector<std::string> names;
names.push_back( "Zero"  );
names.push_back( "One"   );
names.push_back( "Two"   );
names.push_back( "Three" );
names.push_back( "Four"  );
names.push_back( "Five"  );
names.push_back( "Six"   );
names.push_back( "Seven" );
names.push_back( "Eight" );
names.push_back( "Nine"  );
```

Also, let's say I have a vector which defines which elements to loop through:

```
std::vector< int > indices;
indices.push_back( 0 );
indices.push_back( 5 );
indices.push_back( 6 );
```

How can I iterate on the vector `names` according to the elements of the vector `indices` to for example access names: `"Zero"`, `"Five"`, and `"Six"`? I know that:

```
for( vector<string>::iterator it=names.begin() ; it < names.end(); it++)
```

iterate over all elements or elements for which we can find a pattern, e.g., every other element, etc. But how about iterating over elements that have no pattern or difficult to find a pattern? How can a vector be used for iteration in another vector? Something like:

```
for( vector<int>::iterator it=indices.begin() ; it < indices.end(); it++ )
{
     names.at( indices.at( it ) )
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a `std::for_each` call with a lambda to access the indicies (version 1)
Furthermore, you could use a range-based for loop with `rvalues` (version 2)

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>  

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> names;
  names.push_back("Zero");
  names.push_back("One");
  names.push_back("Two");
  names.push_back("Three");
  names.push_back("Four");
  names.push_back("Five");
  names.push_back("Six");
  names.push_back("Seven");
  names.push_back("Eight");
  names.push_back("Nine");

  std::vector< int > indices;
  indices.push_back(0);
  indices.push_back(5);
  indices.push_back(6);

  // version 1
  std::for_each(std::cbegin(indices), std::cend(indices),
    [&](auto &idx) { std::cout << names.at(idx) << "\n";});

  // version 2
  for (auto &&idx : indices)
    std::cout << names.at(idx) << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apparently, `auto` is problematic for `C+11`. The compiler complains about `auto changes meaning in C++11; please remove it`.

Comment: That is specific to `C++14`. if you are using `C++11` you have to replace the `auto` with the specific type.

Answer (score 3):

Your suggestion is almost correct. Instead of `insdices.at(it)`, you should dereference the iterator. But you can do it simply like this:

```
for(int index : indices) {
    names[index];
}
```

Or you can use `vector::at` if you cannot prove that `names.size()` > `indices[i]` for all `i`.

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as this:

```
for( vector<int>::iterator it=indices.begin() ; it != indices.end(); ++it )
{
     names.at( *it );
     names[*it]; // for faster but unvalidated access
     ...
}
```

Note: `++it` could be faster (but cannot be slower) so it is usually used when you do not care if it is postfix or prefix form. `it != container.end()` also is usually used because it is more generic (less than works for random access iterator, but would not for forward iterator for example).